# Tail recursion in Haskell for a function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to learn Haskell and I read about tail recursions. For example I can write the sum function this way :

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + summe xs
```

But also this way

```
summe':: Num a => [a] -> a
summe' x = iterate x 0
    where
    iterate x y | null x    = 0 + y
                | otherwise = iterate (tail x) (head x + y)
```

Could someone tell me how to do it with this function? I am lost

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f 0 = 0
f n = n * f (n-1) + n
```

Comment: By the way, even in the tail recursive variant (with an accumulator), one can still use pattern matching on lists. `head,tail` should be avoided when possible, and here there is no reason to use them.

Answer (score 2):

In order to rewrite the following function using tail-recursion:

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f 0 = 0
f n = n * f (n-1) + n
```

the same approach, which used in `summe'` can be used.

The idea is to start from zero and increment the value until `n` is reached:

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f n = iterate 0 0
  where
    f' x sum = x * sum + x
    iterate x sum | x == n = f' n sum
                  | otherwise = iterate (x + 1) (f' x sum)
```

Thus, if `n` is reached, evaluate the function with `n` and the accumulated sum; otherwise, calculate the function with intermediate sum and value and pass it to the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Well, flipping the "time direction" in `f n = n * f (n-1) + n` by letting  `n = k + 1`, we have

```
f (k+1) = (k+1) * f k + (k+1)
next fk k = (k+1) * fk + (k+1)
```

and thus

```
f n = iterate 0 0
  where
  iterate k fk | k==n = fk
               | otherwise = ....
```